# Save textfield data inside Array and then Load Array in New View

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, xcode, nsuserdefaults

I have written some code which saves the data from textfield into an array and in the new view it loads up fine however the problem is when i go back to my first view and input new value and then press save , on history it doesnt pick up the array. below is what i have done so far:

input:
sterlingpound textfield has 10.21
euro textfield has 0.99

view 1: (has save button and textfields)

```
@IBAction func Save(_ sender: UIButton){
   let sterlingpound = sterlingpound.text
   let euro = euro.text

   let currencyarray = [sterlingpound, euro]
   UserDefaults.standard.set(currencyarray, forKey: "DataKey"
   UserDefaults.standard.synchronize()
}
```

view 2: (loading array )

```
overide func viewDidLoad(){
super.viewDidLoad()

loadArray()
}

func loadArray(){
 let currencyArray = UserDefaults.standard.array(forKey: "DataKey")

 //prints out all values in array
 for element in currencyArray! {
  println(element)
   }
}
```

results:
10.21
0.99

what I need is so that everytime user changes the values inside textfields and presses save all of that data is saved and loaded onto the new viewcontroller.

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are you getting these saved value from UserDefaults whenever load the view?

Comment: Your code looks fine when press back button and you land to previous screen viewDidLoad is not called. May be you should put on viewWillAppear

Comment: @Shashi3456643 It's not good habit to place loading data into `viewWillAppear`. I would rather to make call back function to make all code clear and leave that without any errors/bugs in the future. Why would we load the model in every entry to the VC ?

Comment: @yerpy Correct I agree callback of back function could be right way to do. I was just trying to tell viewWillAppear will let you to debug the problem

Comment: @AmirKhan  Im getting the values every time the user presses save button

Comment: @Shashi3456643 and yerpy  if I were to put the code within viewWillAppear would it still only give me the first values i input into the textfields. My problem is I want it to save data to an arrray everytime user inputs data into textfields and presses save. This data will then be read on my 2nd view where i will place on a label. for example  first input : sterlingpound = 1.99 euro = 0.99 the user then presses save and then edits those fields again and gives new values to them.

Comment: You need to debug the code print the result at each steps. Print the array when you are saving array to UserDefaults. May be one of your field your are getting null or something. I wouldn’t save to UserDefault Singleton I would just pass the Array as callback. Please print the array at each line of code and see where you are loosing the value.

Comment: Even though you can save data using UserDefaults, this doesn't look like a case where you should. You should pass the array from the 1st view controller to the second view controller in the segue that takes you from vc1 to vc2. Do you know how to do that?

Comment: @Jim im quite new to coding could you please explain how i would pass the array to the second view please

Comment: @user7388968 - I was a newbie not that long ago so I'd be happy to help, but I think you'll be better off following a tutorial that really explains it all in detail. It's quite simple to do but terms like `protocol` and `delegate` make it sound difficult. Don't let that scare you. There's no shortage of tutorials about it, but here's one in particular that does a good job: https://makeapppie.com/2016/06/27/using-segues-and-delegates-for-navigation-controllers-in-swift-3-0/ He's passing Strings to the next vc, you just need to pass your Array instead.

Comment: @Jim ty I will look at it

Comment: @user7388968 if you want I can post some answer. All you need to understand how to send data from one view controller to another view controller and get call back to first view controller with data. There are tons of answers are available on stackoverflow anyway if you want I can post some answer.

Comment: @Jim could u possibly give me a small example which demonstrates it would be really appreciated.

Comment: I can't do that here because I'm telling you to take a different approach so it's not relevant to your original question. Try to work through that tutorial and if you get stuck, search for answers already on SO or post a new question and you'll get help. It's worth going through the struggle.

Comment: @user7388968 So you want all past values entered in that both textfields ?
e.g. first time user add "10.21" and "0.99" in text fields then go back edit "11.21" and "1.99" so it should load all these four values in array in view 2.
Are you expecting that ? Pls confirm.